# Pycharm: how to refresh Jupyter after changing the code of an imported module

Tags: jupyter-notebook, pycharm, refresh

I am using a Jupyter notebook in Pycharm and from time to time I update external modules imported by the notebook. For some reason, the kernel ignores my recent changes and behaves as if the code wasn't changed. My current workaround is to stop and restart the Jupyter server but this seems like an overkill. Another thing that might be connected is a warning I get "Notebook kernel doesn't match Project interpreter"

Did anyone encounter a similar problem and knows how to solve it?

Answer (score 3):

I recommend using IPython autoreload extension - [link](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/config/extensions/autoreload.html). Just add the following in your import a separate cell:

```
%load_ext autoreload
%autoreload 2
```

There are different autoreload options. `2` is to reload all modules every time before you use them.

Answer (score 0):

This fixed the issue for me:

```
import importlib
importlib.reload(name_of_your_module)
```

before you use functions from that module on your notebook.